# Linq query to get get count from multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a query wherein I need to get the count from 2 different tables. Here is a very simple form of the query (my query has more joins and conditions but this is the part I am stuck on):

```
select (select count(1) from Table1) as One, (select count(1) from Table2) as Two
```

The following linq queries works but I would like to do the above with a **single linq query sent to the SQL Server**. This query and many other versions I have tried, result in 2 queries sent to the server:

```
var query1 = from m in this.Table1 select m;
var query2 = from sr in this.Table2 select sr;
var final = new { One = query1.Count(), Two = query2.Count() };
```

I also tried this and this also sends 2 queries:

```
var final = from dummy in new List<int> { 1 }
    join one in query1 on 1 equals 1 into ones
    join two in query2 on 1 equals 1 into twos
    select new { One = ones.Count(), Two = twos.Count()};
```

Comment: var final = new { One = (from m in this.Table1 select m).Count(), Two = (from sr in this.Table2 select sr).Count() };

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, and sorry but I have tried that and it results in 2 queries.

Comment: How are you determine that you have two queries? SQL Server doesn't have a single query that contains two FROM (one for each table).  You can use a stored procedure but the procedure will perform two queries.  Having a stored procedure will result in one interface being called between c# and Server, put still will execute two procedures inside SQL Server.

Comment: @Gufus That is not my question.

Comment: @jdweng I have profiler running and it sends 2 separate queries to the server.

Comment: Running a stored procedure will send only one query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make it a single LINQ query that can be translated:

```
var final = (from m in this.Table1.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {
                 One = (from m in this.Table1 select m).Count(),
                 Two = (from sr in this.Table2 select sr).Count()
             }).First();
```

Note that putting the sub-queries into an `IQueryable` variable will cause three separate queries to be sent.

Alternatively, since `Count()` doesn't have a query syntax equivalent, this is a little more compact in lambda syntax:

```
var final = this.Table1.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(t => new {
                 One = this.Table1.Count(),
                 Two = this.Table2.Count()
            }).First();
```

Comment: Thanks! Almost there :) The issue with this query is that if there are no records in `Table1`, it will return no result.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Added `DefaultIfEmpty()` to handle the empty table case.